# PHP: how to compare each key of an associative array to to the others, skipping permutations?

Tags: php, arrays, iteration, associative-array

I have this (seemingly) simple PHP problem:
I have an associative array (which reflects the structure of a DB table, but this is not relevant, here), like this one:

```
----------------------------------
 id  | name            | phone
----------------------------------
   1 | alice           | 12345678
   3 | bob             | 56789012
   9 | zorro           | 90123456
 ... | ...             | ...
----------------------------------
```

I need to iterate through the array to compare (say checking that no two persons have the same phone number) each key to all the others, avoiding to duplicate checks like check(1, 3) and check(3, 1)... (I think I can name these `duplications`, from an equivalent mathematical concept).

```
<?php
  $table = [
    [
      "id" => "1",
      "name" => "alice",
      "phone" => "12345678",
    ], [
    [
      "id" => "3",
      "name" => "bob",
      "phone" => "56789012",
    ], [
    [
      "id" => "9",
      "name" => "zorro",
      "phone" => "90123456",
    ],
  ];
?>
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
<?php
  foreach ($table as $record1) {
    foreach ($table as $record2) {
      check($record1["phone"], $record2["phone"]);
    }
  }
?>
```

But of course this duplicates checks...
Usually (in `C language`, for example), I would sequentially iterate thorugh the array, starting the inner loop from the index next to the current index of the outer loop... But in PHP I've been told I can't sequentially iterate through an associative array... :-(

So the question is: *How to iterate through a PHP associative array to apply a function to any couple of keys, avoiding permutations?*

Comment: The indexes are numerical, but could be not sequential: I could have a **very** "sparse" table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that just like in C:

```
$len = count($table);
for($i = 0; $i < $len - 1; $i++)
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < $len; $j++)
        compare table[$i] and table[$j]
```

If your keys are not sequential, iterate over the array of keys (which is sequential) instead of the actual array:

```
$keys = array_keys($table);
$len = count($keys);
for($i = 0; $i < $len - 1; $i++)
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < $len; $j++)
        compare table[keys[$i]] and table[keys[$j]]
```

Comment: The indexes are numerical, but could be not sequential: I could have a **very** "sparse" table...

Comment: Yessss... I like this idea... :-) (your solution is the first candidate for acceptance... :-)

Comment: Your solution does not completely adapt to my use case: I don't have an associative array (my title is quite wrong... :-(), but a sequential array of associative arrays...

Comment: So the problem probably doesn't exist, I can iterate sequentially... :-( Sorry, everybody...

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array for this:

```
foreach ($table as $record1) {
   if(in_array($record1["phone"], $table){

   }
}
```

this check if the current value is present in the array. read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array('id'=>'1','name'=>'test1','phone'=>'1231231234'),
    array('id'=>'2','name'=>'test2','phone'=>'1231231235'),
    array('id'=>'3','name'=>'test2','phone'=>'1231231234')
);

// sort and find duplicate numbers
$ch = array();
$duplicate = array();
foreach($data as $k=>$d){
    if(in_array($d['phone'],$ch)){
        $duplicate[] = $k;
    }else{
        $ch[$k]=$d['phone'];
    }
}
// remove duplicated numbers from the initial table array
if($duplicate){
    foreach($duplicate as $r)
        unset($data[$r]);
}
// now we have only unique numbers
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```